# Graph only the top names in terms of frequency in a bar plot

Tags: graph, stata

Consider the following toy dataset:

```
clear

input group str10 name n
1     "Jenny"   1
1     "Jenny"   1
1     "Ben"     1
1     "Tiffany" 1
1     "Sun"     1
2     "Jenny"   1
2     "Sun"     1
2     "Tiffany" 1
2     "S"       1
2     "T"       1
2     "R"       1
2     "Y"       1
2     "U"       1
2     "I"       1
2     "E"       1
2     "A"       1
2     "B"       1
3     "U"       1
3     "I"       1
3     "E"       1
3     "A"       1
3     "B"       1
end
```

My code is the following:

```
gen n=1
graph hbar (count) n, over(name, sort(1)) over(group)
```

This shows me all jumbled up names if I use the aforementioned data:

[image]

How can I create a bar graph, which only shows the top 10 categories in terms of frequency, determined separately in each distinct value of `group`?

Comment: Thank you so much to both for your help and insights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified example:

```
clear
input group str50 name n
1     "Jenny"   1
1     "Jenny"   1
1     "Ben"     1
1     "Tiffany" 1
1     "Jenny"   1
1     "Sun"     1
2     "Jenny"   1
2     "Sun"     1
2     "Sun"     1
2     "Tiffany" 1
2     "Tiffany" 1
2     "Tiffany" 1
2     "Tiffany" 1
2     "Tiffany" 1
2     "S"       1
2     "T"       1
2     "R"       1
2     "Y"       1
2     "U"       1
2     "I"       1
2     "E"       1
2     "A"       1
2     "B"       1
3     "U"       1
3     "Ramon"   1
3     "Ramon"   1
3     "Ramon"   1
3     "Ramon"   1
3     "I"       1
3     "I"       1
3     "I"       1
3     "E"       1
3     "A"       1
3     "B"       1
end
```

You can first `collapse` your dataset:

```
collapse (count) n, by(group name)
```

You can then control the number of names drawn by adjusting the frequency threshold as follows:

```
gsort group -n
bysort group: generate tag = _n < 3

graph hbar (asis) n if tag, over(name) over(group) nofill
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate selection of the 10 most frequent classes, we construct here a dataset with 2 groups. In each there are 11 classes. We then show a general method to select the 10 most frequent.

```
* create sandbox dataset 
clear 
set obs 22 
tokenize "`c(ALPHA)'" 
generate name = "" 
generate freq = _n 
generate group = cond(_n <= 11, 1, 2) 
forval j = 1/11 { 
      replace name = "``j''" if inlist(_n, `j', 23 - `j') 
}  

tabulate name group [fw=freq] 
expand freq 
drop freq
```

This is what the dataset looks like (results of the `tabulate` command above):

```
           |         group
      name |         1          2 |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         A |         1         22 |        23 
         B |         2         21 |        23 
         C |         3         20 |        23 
         D |         4         19 |        23 
         E |         5         18 |        23 
         F |         6         17 |        23 
         G |         7         16 |        23 
         H |         8         15 |        23 
         I |         9         14 |        23 
         J |        10         13 |        23 
         K |        11         12 |        23 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |        66        187 |       253
```

The ten most frequent classes are K, J, ..., C, B for group 1 and A, ..., J for group 2.

Here is one way to get and plot the 10 most frequent, determined separately for each group. A user's code starts here, with a user's different number in place of 10 if so desired. Nothing in this case hinges on there being just two groups, as in the example.

```
bysort group name : generate freq = _N
egen tag = tag(group name)
gsort group -tag -freq name
by group: generate selected = _n <= 10
bysort group name (selected) : replace selected = selected[_N]

graph hbar (count) if selected, over(name, sort(1) descending) by(group) nofill scheme(s1color)
```

[image]